# Passing value from aspx.cs page to stored procedure

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I have a line in my aspx.cs page that-

```
cmd.CommandText="INSERT INTO [dbo].[Table] (No_Entered) Values ("+i+")";
```

My question is : what should be its corresponding stored procedure look like?

Thank you in advance :-)

Comment: you want to move this insert stmt inside a SP and call it from C# ? Is that what you are looking to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cmd.CommandText = "YourStoredProcedureName";
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@No_Entered",i); //@No_Entered is parameter name in SP
```

**Stored Procedure**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.YourStoredProcedureName
@No_Entered int
AS
INSERT INTO TABLENAME (No_Entered) VALUES (@No_Entered)
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to create the stored procedure yourself.  It doesn't magically exist on its own.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187926.aspx